# Fitting Zero Truncated Poisson Distribution

Tags: r, probability, distribution

I have the following data:

```r
data=  c(0,1,0,11,2,0,3,0,0,2, 1,3,1, 0,1,0,0,0,2,3,0,0,0,8,1,1,1,0,1,1,
2,7,0,0,0,5,2,3,  6,  1,  1,  5 , 2 , 9 , 0,  0,  1,  21, 16,  2,  9,  6, 
25,  2,  1, 12, 16, 14, 15, 15, 6,  1 ,12 ,12, 13 , 5  ,5 , 6 , 4 , 7 ,11 , 
8 , 4 , 5 , 8,  3 , 8 , 4 , 7 , 4 , 7 , 2 , 5,  6 , 4 , 5 , 1 , 0,  8 , 5,  6 ,
8 , 9,  8, 9 , 7 , 7 , 9 , 8 , 9  ,4  ,4 , 7 ,13 , 9 ,13 ,12, 10 , 9 , 8,  7, 11,  
5 , 5 , 0,  1, 33 , 4 ,22, 19, 22,  9 , 5,4 ,17 , 7 , 7 , 4,  5,  3 , 0 , 0 , 9,  
3,  0 , 0 ,36 ,40,  5 , 4,  0, 11 , 0  ,7  ,5 ,25, 39, 26 , 4 ,20, 12,  4, 17 , 3, 22,
12 ,14 , 8 , 9, 11,  7 ,11, 10 , 9 ,16,  6, 24,  8 , 5 , 6, 14 , 3  ,9 , 4,  1 ,20 , 0 ,
1 , 7  ,9  ,0 ,12,  2, 29 ,56, 16 , 8 ,28,0 ,19, 25 ,35, 87, 56, 66, 60 ,58, 14, 10 ,12, 
13 ,13 ,34, 26, 18 ,13, 22, 13 ,12 ,15 ,41 ,11 ,11 ,11 , 5 , 6,  7 , 8 , 8 ,17, 16,
12, 21, 38 ,34 ,10 ,77 ,41 , 7 ,12 , 1, 16, 20,  8 , 5, 2, 20 , 7 ,16, 12 , 6, 10, 31, 12)
```

I have used the fitdistrplus package to fit this data using poisson distribution.

```r
x=fitdist(data,"pois")
```

Once I use the plot function on x:

```r
plot(x)
```

Two side-by-side plots are constructed by default. One has an empirical and theoretical distribution graph and another has CDF.

**The data set has (29/244)=12% zero values thus My concern here is I want to fit the data using Zero Truncated Poisson distribution and want to have the same type of graph that is produced using fitdistrplus package [ as I mentioned in earlier part: plot(x) ]**

**Any help is appreciated. Thanks**

Comment: The question doesn't make sense to me.  A zero-**truncated** Poisson distribution has *no* zero values in it; this data set has 29/244 (12%) zero values. Are you looking for a zero-**inflated** Poisson? (`pscl::zeroinfl(data ~ 1 )` would work for that ...)

Comment: @BenBolker: The data I have posted there is the original data: Actually I want to make a comparison among the  Poisson, zero truncated Poisson, and zero-inflated Poisson distribution in terms of fitting. More specifically speaking for the Zero truncated poisson data set would be : data=data[data>0].

Comment: There is a statistical problem with your proposal: it rarely (never?) makes sense to compare metrics such as log-likelihood or AIC for models fitted to *different data sets*, which is equivalent to your proposal; you'd be comparing the fit of e.g. a ZIPoisson to the fit of a z-t Poisson to only the positive data.

Comment: @BenBolker: I have revised my concern in more detail, just I want to see which distribution works better in terms of fitting. I just want to explore the subject area. Thanks for your insightful comments.

Comment: @NawaRaj i think you misunderstood the meaning of zero-truncated. it does not mean leaving out predictions with zero values. It is actually modeling the data where you have count data that is always > 0. see https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/zero-truncated-poisson/

Answer (score 1):

The `actuar` package includes a zero-truncated Poisson distribution `dztpois`. You need to specify a starting value.

```r
library(actuar)
d2 <- data[data>0]
xz=fitdist(d2,"ztpois", start=list(lambda=mean(d2)))
plot(xz)
```

As noted in comments, it will not make sense to do a **statistical** comparison between a Poisson fit and zero-truncated Poisson fit to data where the zeros have been discarded.

Comment: I believe this answer was initially accepted, then un-accepted. If this doesn't answer your question, you could edit your question, or leave a comment ...

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification.  By the way, when the actual data is used to fit the distribution:  fitdist(data,"ztpois", start=list(lambda=mean(data))) then it produces the error: mle failed to estimate the parameters with error code 100. Is there any solution to this issue?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but it's pretty much impossible to diagnose without a [mcve]